# React Hooks - How to loop over dynamically created buttons to know which was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a set of movie cards coming from an API. When I click on the movie a modal opens with a button in it. Since there is a lot of movies, I would like to know which button was clicked on, to preserve that button's state as
*'Added to Watchlist'*, if it was clicked on. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Pass a movie name/movie ID as a prop to the button. This id can be stored as a store or prop itself to the Movie card component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a movie name/movie ID as a prop to the button. Id can be stored as a state in the parent component.

```js
//movieCard is API response

state = {
  movideId: '',
  isOpneModal: false,
}

openModal = (cardId) => setState({ movideId: cardId })

render() {
return (
    <Fragment>
      {movieCard.map(card => 
        <MovieCard cardDetails={card} onClick="()=>openModal(card.Id)") />
      )}

      {isOpneModal && <Modal movideId={this.state.movideId} />}
    </Fragment>
)
```